# Table design in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-2, javafx-8

[image: table]

How Can I design a table like above in javafx. I am using tableview and done some css but the design is not as good I want.

Please can anyone tell me how can I achieve the above design

Here is the css I tried

```
.table-view{
   -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.table-view:focused{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

/* Spaltenköpfe
    Struktur column-header-background -> column-header */

.table-view .column-header-background{
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#131313 0%, #424141 100%);
}

.table-view .column-header-background .label{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.table-view .column-header {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.table-view .table-cell{
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.table-row-cell{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-table-cell-border-color, #616161;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-padding: 0.0em; /* 0 */
}
```

current design table

[image: current design]

Comment: Can you please also attach an image of the current view, along with the specific points you are having trouble replicating?

Comment: @sillyfly I have added the current design of table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Css of this figure:

```
.table-view .column-header,
.table-view .column-header .filler,
.table-view .column-header-background .filler {   
    -fx-background-color: derive;
    -fx-stroke: transparent;
    -fx-size:50;
    -fx-alignment: CENTER ;    
    -fx-text-alignment: center;

}
.table-row-cell:filled:hover {

    -fx-size:50;
    -fx-alignment: CENTER;
    -fx-text-alignment: center;


}
.table-view:row-selection {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-fixed-cell-size: 50;
    -fx-alignment: CENTER;
    -fx-text-alignment: center;

}

.table-view .table-column{
    -fx-text-alignment: center;
    -fx-alignment: CENTER 

}
```

Comment: For more information read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html